# Call function on other file from menu Electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I got a custom menu set up in Electron, and I want to call a function - written in another `.js` file - from it.

Code:

Main.js:

```js
const { Menu } = require('electron');

var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
{
    label: 'Foo Menu',
    submenu: [
    {
        label: 'Foo',
        click() {
            // What do I put here?
        },
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+F'
    }
}]);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

src/scripts/index.js:

```js
// The function that I want to be called
function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to export the function:

```
// index.js
function foo() {}
module.exports = foo;
```

and import into the other file with:

```
const foo = require('./index.js');
```

Comment: This does not work - I get this error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Comment: It does! Thank you!